# List of all devices connected to a network

Tags: c++, c, linux, wifi, device

I am learning sockets in C, but i can't find any information about getting a list of all the connected devices in my WLAN network (I am using Linux).

Can anyone provide me of information or where i can start learning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check all the associations on your Wireless Access Point(Wifi router).
Most of the Wifi routers have a web ui where all the associated devices are displayed.

If you have `telnet`/`ssh`/`console` access to your AP, you may try either of the following depending on your wifi hardware and driver.

Broadcomm wireless card:

```
iw assoclist
```

Atheros wireless card:

```
wl_atheros assoclist
```

You may also try `iwlist(8)`, a linux program to get information from a wireless interface.

```
iwlist [interface] scan
```

or

```
iwlist [interface] ap/accesspoint/peers
```

Please refer to your wifi driver documentation for support details.

Comment: my (huawei) router has undocumented commands:S i cant get the assoclist.

Comment: What wireless chipset does it have? You can get it from `dmesg(1)`

Comment: the iwlist command was usefull thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look into the ARP cache.  ARP stands for Address Resolution Protocol and it is how machines turn an IP address into a hardware address.

There is no truly universal way to get a list of all networked devices, but, ARP comes close.

Pinging or just opening and closing a connection to a well known port on every address on your subnet would fill out the ARP cache pretty quickly...

Answer (score 1):

If you know your network IP addres I would advise you to do a broadcast ping to your network broadcast address and note the devices that answer.

For example if your network is `192.168.1.0/24` your broadcast IP address will be `` `192.168.1.255 `` and the command on linux is `ping -b 192.168.1.255`. You can then get the result of the command in your program and work on it to extract the ip of the other connected devices.

**Disclamer :** Some devices may be configured to never answer ping request, then they will be invisible with this method...

**Edit :** If you are using IPv6 you can have a look at the [Neighbor Discovery Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol) (NDP) which kind of replace ARP.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using existing tools in a Linux env. To begin take a look here: [Get all connected IP´s on the Linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910700/get-all-connected-ips-on-the-linux-machine)

Do not re-invent the wheel. If you can.

```
man netstat
```

Comment: I am not re-inventing the wheel, i am learning the wheel.